# Should dot product must be applied on values of same scale

Tags: linear-algebra, products, angle, cross-product

I have points in $n$-dimensions.

I want to find the points which lie on one side of the plane and other lies on the second side and i'm trying to do this with the help of dot-product.

Suppose i have $A = [x_1,x_2,...x_n]$ and $B = [x_1^{\prime},x_2^{\prime}.....x_n^{\prime}]$ and i want to find the sign of the point(which is given by $B$) .

I take the dot-product with $A$ and find out on which side of the plane($A$) does this point lie.

The values in $A$ are between $[-1 ,1]$ and values in $B$ are between $[0,50,000]$, so do i have to normalize $B$ so that both are on same scale or is there any disadvantage of not normalizing $B$?

Comment: Do you mean that the equation of your plane is $x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n = 0$, where $[y_1, \ldots, y_n]$ are the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

Don't normalize. It is not quite clear what is the plane you are asking about, though.

You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691064/7566419

Comment: I mean a hyperplane!

Comment: It's the same... what I mean is that it is not clear what plane($A$) means. Is it the plane $x_1 a_1 + ... + x_n a_n = 0$ (assuming $a_1, ..., a_n$ are the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: regarding the plane or the hyperplane, there's no difference in the answer, it could be a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or any linear form of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Yes, @Javi , these are coordinates